# Gulp error: watch task has to be a function

Tags: javascript, gulp

Here is my gulpfile:

```
// Modules & Plugins
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var myth = require('gulp-myth');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

// Styles Task
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/css/*.css')
        .pipe(concat('all.css'))
        .pipe(myth())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

// Scripts Task
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/js/*.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

// Images Task
gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/img/*')
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'));
});

// Watch Task
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('app/css/*.css', 'styles');
    gulp.watch('app/js/*.js', 'scripts');
    gulp.watch('app/img/*', 'images');
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('styles', 'scripts', 'images', 'watch'));
```

If I run the `images`, `scripts` or `css` task alone it works. I had to add the `return` in the tasks - this wasn't in the book but googling showed me this was required.

The problem I have is that the `default` task errors:

```
[18:41:59] Error: watching app/css/*.css: watch task has to be a function (optionally generated by using gulp.parallel or gulp.series)
    at Gulp.watch (/media/sf_VM_Shared_Dev/webdevadvlocal/gulp/public_html/gulp-book/node_modules/gulp/index.js:28:11)
    at /media/sf_VM_Shared_Dev/webdevadvlocal/gulp/public_html/gulp-book/gulpfile.js:36:10
    at taskWrapper (/media/sf_VM_Shared_Dev/webdevadvlocal/gulp/public_html/gulp-book/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:13:15)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:300:12)
    at asyncRunner (/media/sf_VM_Shared_Dev/webdevadvlocal/gulp/public_html/gulp-book/node_modules/async-done/index.js:36:18)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:444:11)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
```

I think it is because there is also no `return` in the watch task. Also the error message isn't clear - at least to me. I tried adding a `return` after the last `gulp.watch()` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 458, accepted):

In gulp 3.x you could just pass the name of a task to `gulp.watch()` like this:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('app/css/*.css', ['styles']);
  gulp.watch('app/js/*.js', ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch('app/img/*', ['images']);
});
```

In gulp 4.x this is no longer the case. You **have** to pass a function. The customary way of doing this in gulp 4.x is to pass a `gulp.series()` invocation with only one task name. This returns a function that only executes the specified task:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('app/css/*.css', gulp.series('styles'));
  gulp.watch('app/js/*.js', gulp.series('scripts'));
  gulp.watch('app/img/*', gulp.series('images'));
});
```

Comment: So a series of one function... a bit odd isn't it?

Comment: Thank you...

    //watch
 gulp.task('watch', function() {
   gulp.watch('src/images/*.png', gulp.series('images'));
   gulp.watch('src/js/*.js', gulp.series('js'));
   gulp.watch('src/scss/*.scss', gulp.series('css'));
   gulp.watch('src/html/*.html', gulp.series('html'));
 });

Comment: Got stuck till I realized `styles` in `gulp.series('styles'));` is a function. In my case, I had `sass` defined as a function, but I took what was in the `( )` as a destination. For anyone following the "Gulp for Beginners" tutorials and got stuck, the fix is to replace the line `gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);` with `gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.sass', gulp.series('sass'));`

Comment: What's the difference btw `gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.sass', gulp.series('sass'));` and `gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.sass', gulp.series['sass']);`? I tested both lines and saw no change, but I am sure there is a difference (which will come to haunt me later).

Comment: @MonsieurNinja it forms a separation from parallel which strives to run it simultaneously as opposed to series running one task after another, subsequently, or as a series. It is the result of a change that occured to make flow of execution explicitly rather than implicitly. So the previous task execution system was overhauled from Gulp 3.x to how it is explained here for Gulp 4.x. The disambiguation of series vs parallel serves a purpose where some tasks might have untold consequences on others. This has a clearer explanation https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/

Answer (score 22):

**GULP-V4.0**

It is a bit late to answer this right now but still. I was stuck in this problem as well and this is how I got it working.
[image: Gulp structure]

**In detail analysis what I was doing wrong**

1. I forgot to call the reload function when the `watch` noticed some changes in my html files.
2. Since `fireUp` and `KeepWatching` are blocking. They need to be started in parallel rather than serially. So I used the parallel function in the variable run.

Comment: prefer using code block over screenshot

Answer (score 19):

thanks for all

```
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.sass', gulp.series('sass'));
});
```

for version gulp 4.xx

Comment: It should be `gulp.series('sass')`

Comment: No, it does not need to be a series if its just one task.

Comment: @Vortilion the `['taskName']` dictates that you're basically passing a list, even if it's only one task...

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me in Gulp 4.0

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
      gulp.watch('src/images/*.png', gulp.series('images'));
      gulp.watch('src/js/*.js', gulp.series('js'));
      gulp.watch('src/scss/*.scss', gulp.series('css'));
      gulp.watch('src/html/*.html', gulp.series('html'));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

//Check what worked for me

```
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('css/shop.css', gulp.series(['shop']));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, work for me this:
(in gulpfile.js)
(install: gulp, gulp sass)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));

var cssDest = 'style';
var cssInputFile = 'source/style.scss';
var watchedFiles = 'source/**/*.scss';




gulp.task('buildcss', function(){
    return gulp.src(cssInputFile)
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(watchedFiles, gulp.series(['buildcss']));
});
```

Commend: **gulp watch** 
(v 4.0)

Answer (score 0):

On my side, I also had to add "{usePolling: true}" this to get it working:

```
gulp.watch(paths.js_src + '/*.js', {usePolling: true}, gulp.series(projectScripts, ondemandProjectScripts))
```

I think it's because my code runs into a docker container.