# Dynamically generate Gulp 4 tasks from entries in an object

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am trying to dynamically generate Gulp 4 tasks for each of the entries in an object.

The object contains a bundle name and an array of files to include in the bundle.

It looks like this:

```
const scripts = {
    dest: 'dist/js/',
    bundles: {
        'main': [
            'src/js/script-1.js',
            'src/js/script-2.js',
        ],
        'vendor': [
            'src/js/script-3.js'
        ]
    }
};
```

I want to create two gulp tasks for each entry in the "bundles" object, one to build the scripts and one to watch for changes.

Here is what I have so far:

```
for (const [name, files] of Object.entries(scripts.bundles)) {

    const buildTaskName = 'build:' + name;
    const watchTaskName = 'watch:' + name;

    gulp.task(buildTaskName, function() {
            return gulp.src(files)
                       .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
                       ... Plugins Here ...
                       .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
                       .pipe(gulp.dest(scripts.dest))   
    });

    gulp.task(watchTaskName, function() {
        gulp.watch(files, buildTaskName)
    });
};
```

When I run `gulp build:main` the task works and I get a new file called main.min.js in the dist folder.

However, when I run `gulp watch:main` I get his error:

```
Error: watching src/js/script-1.js,src/js/script-2.js: watch task has to be a function 
(optionally generated by using gulp.parallel or gulp.series)
```

I'm not sure why the build task works, but the watch task doesn't. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about if you try `gulp.watch(files, gulp.series(buildTaskName))`

Comment: That was the problem, guess I spent too long staring at it yesterday, such a simple mistake. I posted the new code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Sven's answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39665899/5022211), in Gulp 4 you have to pass a function to gulp.watch, not just the name of a function...

By changing the watch task to:

```
gulp.task(watchTaskName, function() {
    return gulp.watch(files, gulp.series(buildTaskName));
});
```

The watch task works. I hope this helps anyone else who may be trying to build a similar Gulp setup.